# Java Random double in interval [-1000, 1000]

Tags: java, random

In java I have:

```
Random random = new Random();
double randomNum = random.nextDouble();
```

which creates a random number between 0 and 1. However I want a number between -1000 and 1000, how would I scale this?

Thanks

Comment: And there seems to be some confusion as to whether you want a random `double`, or `int`... which do you want?

Comment: A random double, thanks for help.

Comment: FYI: All the function here produce `[-1000, 1000)` i.e. you will never get 1000, but you can get -1000.

Answer (score 5):

2 possibilities:

1. [less dense]: multiple your results by 2000, and subtract 1000
   from the result. It won't be as 'dense' as possibility 2.
2. get a random int in range [-1000,999], and add a random double in
   range [0,1].

Note that possibility 2 ensures better randomness and better 'density' of your numbers, at the cost of 2 random calls [which might be expansive, if it is an issue].

Comment: Can you explain why option 1 is "less dense in [0,1]"? I've created a histogram with bucket width one (using `floor`) and it looked totally normal around the center.

Comment: @ziggystar: doubles are not all real numbers. There are finite numbers of doubles in range [0,1]. Now, assume there are k double numbers in the range [0,1]. With option 1, you get only k numbers in your range [-1000,1000], while with option 2 you get 2000*k possibilities! thus, it is less random - some numbers may not appear in option1, but they can in option 2. The density in my answer means the possible distance between two numbers, the minimum distance in option1 is much bigger then in option2, and thus it is less dense.

Comment: Thanks. I understand that and I think I was confused by your comment, which I interpreted as meaning "less dense only between 0 and 1".

Answer (score 1):

Um, maths?

```
double randomNum = (random.nextDouble()-0.5d) * 2000;
```

Comment: Note that it will be less dense then the original function in range (0,1), and thus less random.

Answer (score 1):

```
Random random = new Random();
double randomNum = (random.nextDouble() * 2000.0d) - 1000.0d;
```

Comment: Note that it will be less dense then the original function in range (0,1), and thus less random.

Answer (score 0):

Try this algorithm:

1. Generate a random value in the range 0 to 1.
2. multiply that value by 2000 (the size of the desired range).
3. subtract 1000 from the result of step 2 (move the value into the desired range).

Answer (score 0):

This gives you a number on that range

```
double randomNum = (random.nextDouble() * 2000) -1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Random random = new Random();
int randomNum = random.nextInt(2000) - 1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a general function you could use to linearly rescale a number between zero and one (`val01`) to a different range (`min`..`max`):

```
    public static double rescale(double val01, double min, double max) {
        return val01 * (max - min) + min;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double doubleBetween(double start, double end) {
    Random random = new Random();

    // We need 64 bits because double have 53 bits precision, so int is too short
    // We have now a value between 0 and Long.MAX_VALUE.
    long value = -1L;
    while (value < 0)
      value = Math.abs(random.nextLong()); // Caution, Long.MIN_VALUE returns negative !


    // Cast to double
    double valueAsDouble = (double) value;

    // Scale so that Long.MAX_VALUE is exactly 1 !
    double diff = (end-start)/(double) Long.MAX_VALUE;


    return start + valueAsDouble*diff;
}
```

This will give the correct interval including both ends with full double precision. doubles have a special -0.0 value (the negative zero) which will not be given by this routine.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public  static double randomInterval(double minValue,double maxValue){
    Random random = new Random();
    double r;
    do {
        r = random.nextDouble();
    } while (r < minValue || r >= maxValue);
    return r;
}
```

##### Example :

```
double a = randomInterval(-1000,1000) ;
```